# Verifying the values from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, verify

I'm quite new to mysql tables and I know I should use PDO or mysqli, but this is just an example for school.

Here's my problematic code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

if ($uporab != $row['uporabnisko'] || $pass != $row['geslo']){  
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Uporabnisko ime ali geslo ni pravilno! Prosim poskusi znova.")';
    echo '</script>';

    header('Location: index1.php');
}
else{
    header('Location: Stranzaindexom.html');
}
}
```

When I use "while" I get error popped out 5 times (I think it depends on how many values are in table in database), but when I don't use while, than I get checked just first id (first row) in table.. I  checked for other answers but I haven't found the proper one.. 
Any help?

PS: connection to the database is successful, and taking values of table is good to.. So my problems just lay somewhere here.

Comment: Please stop using mysql since it is deprecated, and start using mysqli and PDO instead..

Comment: call exit; after header('Location ....'); to stop the code from running after you redirect

Comment: Naruto, i told you i'm new at this and i need this just as simple school project, where they teach us that way. I'm gonna learn PDO after finishing this. 

Bumperbox: thanks, that solve one problem, but now i dont get any pop out window that says "Wrong name / password".

Comment: maybe you can dump the $row and see if you get the correct data from DB And its not a good idea print something before header("Location") page will redirect in instant so you may not see the alerts.

Comment: If i dont redirect, than i'm getting the blank page after wrond id/password.

Comment: Then you need to give that alert in your index1.php not your current page.

Comment: You're outputting before header, you can't do that and it won't work. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this

Why do we need to select all the records and check all the records the best is to pull only that record which is necessary.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * name FROM usertable WHERE uporabnisko='$uporab' AND geslo = '$pass'");
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Uporabnisko ime ali geslo ni pravilno! Prosim poskusi znova.")';
    echo '</script>';
    echo "<script language='javascript'> window.location='index1.php'; </script>";
}
else
{
    echo "<script language='javascript'> window.location='Stranzaindexom.html'; </script>";
}
```

Comment: Well it does not give any errors, but it's not going forward, it keeps me on my first page, doesnt proceed. Like none of parameters are correct.

Comment: Then use this `echo "<script language='javascript'> window.location='index1.php'; </script>";` instead of `header('Location: index1.php');`

Comment: Well when I try window.location it puts out error for wrong id/password (underneath its a blank page with warning message about mysql_fetch_array expecting 1.. boolean ... and something forward) but when i click "Ok" on popout, it tranfers me back to index1.php

Answer (score 0):

Think reverse check the positive case and give the alert on else like:

```
if ($uporab == $row['uporabnisko'] && $pass == $row['geslo']){
    header('Location: Stranzaindexom.html');
    exit();
} else {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Uporabnisko ime ali geslo ni pravilno! Prosim poskusi znova.")';
    echo '</script>';
}
```

Or use the username and password at the sql and give limit 1 so you dont need a while becouse it garanteus that result set will be 1 row or 0 row:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$escapedUsername."' AND password='".$escapedPassword."' LIMIT 1");
```